# Combine data sets

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

There are two table below, `project_check_history` is a history of some checked did on a project and `project_check_metrics` is that table holding the metrics collected about that project.

Tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE project_check_history (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id int4,
  check_type varchar,
  checked_at timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE project_check_metrics (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id int4,
  metrics json,
  created_at timestamp
);

INSERT INTO project_check_history(project_id, check_type, checked_at) 
  VALUES 
      (1, 'instant', '2016-09-25'),
      (1, 'scheduled', '2016-09-24'),
      (1, 'scheduled', '2016-09-23');

INSERT INTO project_check_metrics(project_id, metrics, created_at) 
  VALUES 
      (1, '{ "name": "10" }', '2016-09-25'),

      (1, '{ "name": "3" }', '2016-09-24'),
      (1, '{ "name": "5" }', '2016-09-24'),
      (1, '{ "name": "1" }', '2016-09-24'),

      (1, '{ "name": "3" }', '2016-09-23'),
      (1, '{ "name": "2" }', '2016-09-23'),
      (1, '{ "name": "1" }', '2016-09-23');
```

Also available on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d01a)

Using that data I am trying to build a query that will return this output:

```
project_id, checked_at, metrics,       check_type
1,          2016-09-25, {'name': '10'}, instant
1,          2016-09-25, {'name': '3'},  instant
1,          2016-09-25, {'name': '5'},  instant
1,          2016-09-25, {'name': '1'},  instant
1,          2016-09-24, {'name': '3'},  scheduled
1,          2016-09-24, {'name': '5'},  scheduled
1,          2016-09-24, {'name': '1'},  scheduled
1,          2016-09-23, {'name': '3'},  scheduled
1,          2016-09-23, {'name': '2'},  scheduled
1,          2016-09-23, {'name': '1'},  scheduled
```

Inside `project_check_history` there is a row with a `instant check_type`, 
in those situations I need to look inside the table and find the closest date to `2016-09-25` which is of `scheduled check_type` that will be `2016-09-24`, once we fond that date, I want to bring all the data found inside `project_check_metrics` for both dates(2016-09-25, 2016-09-24), and associate that data with the `2016-09-25` which is the date from `project_check_history`.

> Update

Here is my attempt at creating this query

```
SELECT pch.project_id
     , pch.checked_at::date
     , min(pch.check_type) AS check_type
     , array_agg(metrics)
     , count(*)
FROM project_check_history pch
INNER JOIN project_check_metrics pcm
        ON pcm.project_id = pch.project_id
WHERE (pch.check_type = 'instant' AND pcm.created_at::date 
        IN (
                SELECT checked_at 
                FROM project_check_history 
                WHERE checked_at <= pch.checked_at 
                LIMIT 2
            )
        ) 
    OR ( pch.check_type = 'scheduled' AND
         pcm.created_at::date = pch.checked_at::date)
GROUP BY pch.project_id, pch.checked_at::date
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The above almost works, I still have a problem with my condition

```
SELECT checked_at 
FROM project_check_history 
WHERE checked_at <= pch.checked_at
```

what I would like to do here is to SELECT all the `checked_at` where `check_type` is `instant` but stop as soon as I find `check_type schedule` and return N rows containing `instant` where the `checked_at < pch.checked_at` and just one row containing `check_type schedule` where `checked_at < pch.checked_at`

Expected output from the above data set
checked_at: 2016-09-25, 2015-09-24

Please let me know if you see a better way of creating this query.

> Update

Solution for subquery [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150690/extract-all-rows-until-and-including)

> Update

Running this query on big data sets does not perform :(

Comment: Thanks for providing the script for the tables and the sample data. It is however better to include that in your question as well, just in case SQLFiddle is not reachable (which happens more often then not)

Comment: Will the row with `scheduled` always be before the one with `instant`? And why are you using a `timestamp` if you are casting that to a `date` all the time?

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d01a/3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i can change it to a `date`, here is a solution to my problem, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d01a/9, but it does not work when I have a lot of metrics