# Extract all rows until and including

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

I would like to extract all the rows from a table until and including `check_type = 'schedule' and checked_at < '2016-09-26'`, in this situation I don't have a lower bound for `checked_at`, the lower bound could be the `checked_at` value of the first row which has the type `scheduled`, but I don't see how I can get that.

```
CREATE TABLE project_check_history (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id int4,
  check_type varchar,
  checked_at timestamp
);

INSERT INTO project_check_history(project_id, check_type, checked_at) 
  VALUES 
      (1, 'instant', '2016-09-26'),
      (1, 'instant', '2016-09-25'),
      (1, 'scheduled', '2016-09-24'),
      (1, 'instant', '2016-09-23'),
      (1, 'scheduled', '2016-09-23');
      (1, 'instant', '2016-09-22'),
      (1, 'scheduled', '2016-09-21');
```

This is part of a bigger question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150649/combine-data-sets?noredirect=1#comment286716_150649), but I'm really stuck, and don't see how I can do it.

Expected output it will be:

```
checked_at
2016-09-26
2016-09-25
2016-09-24
```

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the rows will be in descending order of the `checked_at`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ using that data set the result will not include `instant, 2016-09-23` it will stop at the first occurrence of `schedule`, and in this case it will return the `checked_at` for the first 3 rows

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ then it will continue till `scheduled 2016-09-23` and return `2016-09-26, 2016-09-25, 2016-09-23`, no just once, but will not matter anyway, because this will be part of another condition that will pick rows where a `date IN this set of dates`, and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want. If there is no row with `check_type = 'scheduled'` in the specified interval, it will return no rows at all. If you want all the rows instead, it will have to be slightly modified:

```
WITH find_schedule AS
  ( SELECT created_at
    FROM project_check_history
    WHERE check_type = 'scheduled'
      AND checked_at <= '2016-09-26'
    ORDER BY checked_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) 
SELECT  -- DISTINCT 
    created_at
FROM project_check_history
WHERE checked_at <= '2016-09-26'
  AND checked_at >= (TABLE first_schedule) ;
```